# spring cloud 2020.0.4 and spring-kafka:2.6.6 compatibility

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-kafka

I am using spring cloud 2020.0.2 and spring-kafka:2.6.6 with spring boot 2.5.8. This works fine.
But when I upgrade spring cloud to 2020.0.4 then spring kafka throws following error.

***MessageHandling exception, Missing header kafka_acknowledgement***.

Can anyone please help me if spring cloud 2020.0.2 and spring-kafka:2.6.6 is compatible?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2020.0.x switched to Spring Boot 2.5 in 2020.0.3 (see https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud).

Boot 2.5.x uses Spring for Apache Kafka 2.7.x.